# how to wrap log4j logger inside slf4j logger?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I have a log4j.Logger configured like this:

```
private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("loggerName");
```

and it works just fine. 
However, for camel purposes I need to get slf4j and trying to feed log4j instead of slf4j causing me a ClassCastException.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
public org.slf4j.Logger getSlf4jLogger() {
        return org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("loggerName");
    }
```

Is there any way to wrap log4j Logger inside of slf4j or use another trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one option. Remove the log4j's libraries. Use `log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar`.

So, in *jars view*, you can have:

```
log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar
            ↓
    slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
            ↓
logback-classic-1.0.13.jar
  logback-core-1.0.13.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a misunderstanding about slf4j here: It is a facade API with bindings to several popular logging frameworks, log4j being one of them.

Camel uses slf4j for its own logging so not to impose the use of a particular logging framework on you. If you use log4j then you can keep your code as it is and besides the slf4j-api.jar you need to add the slf4j-log4j12.jar to your classpath. Now your log4j logging configuration also applies to the log output of Camel.